# Pandas convert data from two tables into third table. Cross Referencing and converting unique rows to columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following tables:

**Table A**

```
listData = {'id':[1,2,3],'date':['06-05-2021','07-05-2021','17-05-2021']}
pd.DataFrame(listData,columns=['id','date'])
```

[image]

**Table B**

```
detailData = {'code':['D123','F268','A291','D123','F268','A291'],'id':['1','1','1','2','2','2'],'stock':[5,5,2,10,11,8]}
pd.DataFrame(detailData,columns=['code','id','stock'])
```

[image]

**OUTPUT TABLE**

```
output = {'code':['D123','F268','A291'],'06-05-2021':[5,5,2],'07-05-2021':[10,11,8]}
pd.DataFrame(output,columns=['code','06-05-2021','07-05-2021'])
```

[image]

Note: The code provided is hard coded code for the output. I need to generate the output table from Table A and Table B

Here is brief explanation of how the output table is generated if it is not self explanatory.

1. The id column needs to be cross reference from Table A to Table B and the dates should be put instead in Table B
2. Then all the unique dates in Table B should be made into columns and the corresponding stock values need to be shifted to then newly created date columns.

I am not sure where to start to do this. I am new to pandas and have only ever used it for simple data manipulation. If anyone can suggest me where to get started, it will be of great help.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] or more specific, please provide copy/pasteable data instead of pictures.

Comment: @Andreas Added the code that can be copy pasted for the tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
tableA['id'] = tableA['id'].astype(str)
tableB.merge(tableA, on='id').pivot('code', 'date', 'stock')
```

Output:

```
date  06-05-2021  07-05-2021
code                        
A291           2           8
D123           5          10
F268           5          11
```

Details:

- First, `merge` on id, this is like doing a SQL join.  First, the
  dtypes much match, hence using `astype` to str.
- Next, reshape the dataframe using `pivot` to get code by date.

Comment: Didn't realise it could be this simple, I guess I should study pandas commands in detail. Thanks

Comment: @dracarys Yes, pandas is a very extensive library.  There are many powerful data manipulation command at your disposal in there.  Be safe and stay healthy.  Happy coding!